# Xamarin when under source control Directory not found and illegal characters in path

Tags: git, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and to using git. When i create a new xamarin forms project and add it to git when compiling i get two errors:

1. `XARDF7004: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.` – But doesn't tell me what path is throwing the error.
2. `XARDF7023: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor.class'.` – I have checked and this file is present in the correct folder.

If I copy the project and put it in another folder on my PC not under any source control it compiles and works as it should.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Git under an IDE like VS ?

Comment: @Cfun I create the project without selecting soruce control in Visual studio, I then use the git bash program to create a git repo in the project folder and use the Team explorer tab in VS to make commits and push etc

Comment: Not sure if it matters but which version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2019 Community, I normally develop C# WPF and use git this way but haven't run into an issue like this before, tried recreating the git repo multiple times but still happening

Comment: You could post the issue to  : **Help->Send Feedback -> report a problem**